# Download array of images from array of urls

Tags: android, android-glide, android-networking, kotlin-coroutines

I want to download array of images from my array of urls.
I need to use coroutines and need to know when all images are loaded and stored in one array as bitmaps or drawables.
As for me i researched glide, but didn't find anything useful for my problem cause it download only one image as lazy.

As a result i want to see kotlin coroutine that will download all images and store it in one array.

Comment: why dont you use rxjava zip function for that

Comment: I want to deal with it only with coroutines, without rxjava functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get Data by url and load image by picasso

Visit https://medium.com/@crossphd/android-image-loading-from-a-string-url-6c8290b82c5e